# The Android RadioButton style in SDK 23

Tags: android, android-layout

The pink `radio` button below is created by xml, the green is created by programmatically

[image]

I want to know how to create the pink `radio` button by programmatically. The style is `auto`?

top is green radiobutton, bottom is pink radiobutton
[image]

Comment: what is the issue.. create a style with  
<style name="content_check_box">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/green</item>

    </style>

& set it to your programatically generated radio buttons style.

Comment: did you click the link? Is the picture about my question. I want to create the style of pink radiobutton by java code.

Comment: w8 i am giving you code for it

Comment: w8? What's means? Can you give me the right code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a style field Like, insert your color in colorAccent.

```
 <style name="content_check_box">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Now Create your radio button, similarly you are showing in that image.
But add style in first line .

```
final RadioButton radioButton =new RadioButton(this or context,R.style.content_check_box )
```

Comment: I use your code, find have no animation when i check it.

Comment: Show me your style.xml file and java file where you apply this